# A method towards making a binary tree dictionary in java

Tags: java, dictionary

First of all, thanks in advance!

So I'm making a Dictionary Binary Tree in java where integers can be inserted as well as searched for although I'm confused which method is best to use to do this. 
I've considered the following two methods:

HashTable

TreeMap

Which way is better and why?

Comment: First of all your question has nothing to do with programming and secondly a simple google search will reveal the answer to your question. Flagged

Comment: TreeMap uses a binary tree internally.  But you can find this out for yourself in about 20 seconds ... by reading the javadocs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want / need a *binary tree* then use `TreeMap`.  It uses a binary tree, and `HashMap` / `LinkedHashMap` / `ConcurrentHashMap` / `Hashtable` don't.

Otherwise, any of the classes mentioned can be used to implement a dictionary where you can insert (`put`) and search for (`get`) entries.

---

I'm not going to explain the differences between the classes because I'm sure someone has already done it ... Google it.  I'm merely going to say that the `Hashtable` class is probably a bad choice.  As the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) says:

> *"If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use `HashMap` in place of `Hashtable`. If a thread-safe highly-concurrent implementation is desired, then it is recommended to use `ConcurrentHashMap` in place of `Hashtable`."*

Comment: Thanks a lot @Stephen C . That was the answer i needed.